# QGIS "python3.exe: No module named gdal_merge"

Tags: qgis, gdal, python-3

I just would like to merge several raster of GeoTIFF but after the QGIS update from 3.3 to 3.4, even this simple tool can´t be used for the same raster anymore.

```
 GDAL command:python3 -m gdal_merge -separate -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o "F:/Data Outcomes/mergeTest3.tif" --optfile C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_83de971f88c4406dbddd1acd440e9c00/5b473ea0219940439f0fb5c63b9ee370/mergeInputFiles.txt
```

`GDAL command output: E:\QGIS3.4.2\bin\python3.exe: No module named gdal_merge
Execution completed in 3.12 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'F:/Data '
'Outcomes/mergeTest3.tif'}`

I already tried to reinstall QGIS couple of times and also on different computers (Windows10), but it still doesn´t work. Does anyone have the same issue or perhaps know how to solve the issue?

Comment: @B. Zhg I probably answered your question

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution - module r.patch, available in QGIS desktop with GRASS - worked for me

[image: screenshot of finding r.patch]

Answer (score 0):

In the menus above go to `raster-->miscellaneous-->build virtual raster`
This will create the desired merge you want. Then save it to a "real" file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use OSGeo4W shell ?

From my Window 10 / QGIS 3.4 installation, the following command line was succesfull.

```
gdal_merge.bat -n 255 -a_nodata 255 -of GTiff -o "output.tif" "input1.tif" "input2.tif"
```

So, in your case, I guess it would be something like :

```
gdal_merge.bat -separate -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o "output.tif" --optfile c:\path\to\file.txt
```

You may also check your environment variables in QGIS / Settings | Options / System menu or in your Window system properties.

More details are available on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33386.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script gdal_merge.py and copy this code:

```py
from glob import glob

try:
    from osgeo import gdal
except ImportError:
    import gdal

try:
    progress = gdal.TermProgress_nocb
except:
    progress = gdal.TermProgress


import sys
import math

__version__ = '$id$'[5:-1]
verbose = 0
quiet = 0


# =============================================================================
def raster_copy( s_fh, s_xoff, s_yoff, s_xsize, s_ysize, s_band_n,
                 t_fh, t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize, t_band_n,
                 nodata=None ):

    if nodata is not None:
        return raster_copy_with_nodata(
            s_fh, s_xoff, s_yoff, s_xsize, s_ysize, s_band_n,
            t_fh, t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize, t_band_n,
            nodata )

    if verbose != 0:
        print('Copy %d,%d,%d,%d to %d,%d,%d,%d.' \
              % (s_xoff, s_yoff, s_xsize, s_ysize,
             t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize ))

    s_band = s_fh.GetRasterBand( s_band_n )
    t_band = t_fh.GetRasterBand( t_band_n )

    data = s_band.ReadRaster( s_xoff, s_yoff, s_xsize, s_ysize,
                             t_xsize, t_ysize, t_band.DataType )
    t_band.WriteRaster( t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize,
                        data, t_xsize, t_ysize, t_band.DataType )


    return 0

# =============================================================================
def raster_copy_with_nodata( s_fh, s_xoff, s_yoff, s_xsize, s_ysize, s_band_n,
                             t_fh, t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize, t_band_n,
                             nodata ):
    try:
        import numpy as Numeric
    except ImportError:
        import Numeric

    if verbose != 0:
        print('Copy %d,%d,%d,%d to %d,%d,%d,%d.' \
              % (s_xoff, s_yoff, s_xsize, s_ysize,
             t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize ))

    s_band = s_fh.GetRasterBand( s_band_n )
    t_band = t_fh.GetRasterBand( t_band_n )

    data_src = s_band.ReadAsArray( s_xoff, s_yoff, s_xsize, s_ysize,
                                   t_xsize, t_ysize )
    data_dst = t_band.ReadAsArray( t_xoff, t_yoff, t_xsize, t_ysize )

    nodata_test = Numeric.equal(data_src,nodata)
    to_write = Numeric.choose( nodata_test, (data_src, data_dst) )

    t_band.WriteArray( to_write, t_xoff, t_yoff )

    return 0

# =============================================================================
def names_to_fileinfos( names ):
    """
    Translate a list of GDAL filenames, into file_info objects.
    names -- list of valid GDAL dataset names.
    Returns a list of file_info objects.  There may be less file_info objects
    than names if some of the names could not be opened as GDAL files.
    """

    file_infos = []
    for name in names:
        fi = file_info()
        if fi.init_from_name( name ) == 1:
            file_infos.append( fi )

    return file_infos

# *****************************************************************************
class file_info:
    """A class holding information about a GDAL file."""

    def init_from_name(self, filename):
        """
        Initialize file_info from filename
        filename -- Name of file to read.
        Returns 1 on success or 0 if the file can't be opened.
        """
        fh = gdal.Open( filename )
        if fh is None:
            return 0

        self.filename = filename
        self.bands = fh.RasterCount
        self.xsize = fh.RasterXSize
        self.ysize = fh.RasterYSize
        self.band_type = fh.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
        self.projection = fh.GetProjection()
        self.geotransform = fh.GetGeoTransform()
        self.ulx = self.geotransform[0]
        self.uly = self.geotransform[3]
        self.lrx = self.ulx + self.geotransform[1] * self.xsize
        self.lry = self.uly + self.geotransform[5] * self.ysize

        ct = fh.GetRasterBand(1).GetRasterColorTable()
        if ct is not None:
            self.ct = ct.Clone()
        else:
            self.ct = None

        return 1

    def report( self ):
        print('Filename: '+ self.filename)
        print('File Size: %dx%dx%d' \
              % (self.xsize, self.ysize, self.bands))
        print('Pixel Size: %f x %f' \
              % (self.geotransform[1],self.geotransform[5]))
        print('UL:(%f,%f)   LR:(%f,%f)' \
              % (self.ulx,self.uly,self.lrx,self.lry))

    def copy_into( self, t_fh, s_band = 1, t_band = 1, nodata_arg=None ):
        """
        Copy this files image into target file.
        This method will compute the overlap area of the file_info objects
        file, and the target gdal.Dataset object, and copy the image data
        for the common window area.  It is assumed that the files are in
        a compatible projection ... no checking or warping is done.  However,
        if the destination file is a different resolution, or different
        image pixel type, the appropriate resampling and conversions will
        be done (using normal GDAL promotion/demotion rules).
        t_fh -- gdal.Dataset object for the file into which some or all
        of this file may be copied.
        Returns 1 on success (or if nothing needs to be copied), and zero one
        failure.
        """
        t_geotransform = t_fh.GetGeoTransform()
        t_ulx = t_geotransform[0]
        t_uly = t_geotransform[3]
        t_lrx = t_geotransform[0] + t_fh.RasterXSize * t_geotransform[1]
        t_lry = t_geotransform[3] + t_fh.RasterYSize * t_geotransform[5]

        # figure out intersection region
        tgw_ulx = max(t_ulx,self.ulx)
        tgw_lrx = min(t_lrx,self.lrx)
        if t_geotransform[5] < 0:
            tgw_uly = min(t_uly,self.uly)
            tgw_lry = max(t_lry,self.lry)
        else:
            tgw_uly = max(t_uly,self.uly)
            tgw_lry = min(t_lry,self.lry)

        # do they even intersect?
        if tgw_ulx >= tgw_lrx:
            return 1
        if t_geotransform[5] < 0 and tgw_uly <= tgw_lry:
            return 1
        if t_geotransform[5] > 0 and tgw_uly >= tgw_lry:
            return 1

        # compute target window in pixel coordinates.
        tw_xoff = int((tgw_ulx - t_geotransform[0]) / t_geotransform[1] + 0.1)
        tw_yoff = int((tgw_uly - t_geotransform[3]) / t_geotransform[5] + 0.1)
        tw_xsize = int((tgw_lrx - t_geotransform[0])/t_geotransform[1] + 0.5) \
                   - tw_xoff
        tw_ysize = int((tgw_lry - t_geotransform[3])/t_geotransform[5] + 0.5) \
                   - tw_yoff

        if tw_xsize < 1 or tw_ysize < 1:
            return 1

        # Compute source window in pixel coordinates.
        sw_xoff = int((tgw_ulx - self.geotransform[0]) / self.geotransform[1])
        sw_yoff = int((tgw_uly - self.geotransform[3]) / self.geotransform[5])
        sw_xsize = int((tgw_lrx - self.geotransform[0]) \
                       / self.geotransform[1] + 0.5) - sw_xoff
        sw_ysize = int((tgw_lry - self.geotransform[3]) \
                       / self.geotransform[5] + 0.5) - sw_yoff

        if sw_xsize < 1 or sw_ysize < 1:
            return 1

        # Open the source file, and copy the selected region.
        s_fh = gdal.Open( self.filename )

        return \
            raster_copy( s_fh, sw_xoff, sw_yoff, sw_xsize, sw_ysize, s_band,
                         t_fh, tw_xoff, tw_yoff, tw_xsize, tw_ysize, t_band,
                         nodata_arg )


# =============================================================================
def Usage():
    print('Usage: gdal_merge.py [-o out_filename] [-of out_format] [-co NAME=VALUE]*')
    print('                     [-ps pixelsize_x pixelsize_y] [-tap] [-separate] [-q] [-v] [-pct]')
    print('                     [-ul_lr ulx uly lrx lry] [-init "value [value...]"]')
    print('                     [-n nodata_value] [-a_nodata output_nodata_value]')
    print('                     [-ot datatype] [-createonly] input_files')
    print('                     [--help-general]')
    print('')

# =============================================================================
#
# Program mainline.
#

def main( argv=None ):
    global verbose, quiet
    verbose = 0
    quiet = 0
    names = []
    format = 'GTiff'
    out_file = 'out.tif'

    ulx = None
    psize_x = None
    separate = 0
    copy_pct = 0
    nodata = None
    a_nodata = None
    create_options = []
    pre_init = []
    band_type = None
    createonly = 0
    bTargetAlignedPixels = False

    gdal.AllRegister()
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    argv = gdal.GeneralCmdLineProcessor( argv )
    if argv is None:
        sys.exit( 0 )

    # Parse command line arguments.
    i = 1
    while i < len(argv):
        arg = argv[i]

        if arg == '-o':
            i = i + 1
            out_file = argv[i]

        elif arg == '-v':
            verbose = 1

        elif arg == '-q' or arg == '-quiet':
            quiet = 1

        elif arg == '-createonly':
            createonly = 1

        elif arg == '-separate':
            separate = 1

        elif arg == '-pct':
            copy_pct = 1

        elif arg == '-ot':
            i = i + 1
            band_type = gdal.GetDataTypeByName( argv[i] )
            if band_type == gdal.GDT_Unknown:
                print('Unknown GDAL data type: %s' % argv[i])
                sys.exit( 1 )

        elif arg == '-init':
            i = i + 1
            str_pre_init = argv[i].split()
            for x in str_pre_init:
                pre_init.append(float(x))

        elif arg == '-n':
            i = i + 1
            nodata = float(argv[i])

        elif arg == '-a_nodata':
            i = i + 1
            a_nodata = float(argv[i])

        elif arg == '-f':
            # for backward compatibility.
            i = i + 1
            format = argv[i]

        elif arg == '-of':
            i = i + 1
            format = argv[i]

        elif arg == '-co':
            i = i + 1
            create_options.append( argv[i] )

        elif arg == '-ps':
            psize_x = float(argv[i+1])
            psize_y = -1 * abs(float(argv[i+2]))
            i = i + 2

        elif arg == '-tap':
            bTargetAlignedPixels = True

        elif arg == '-ul_lr':
            ulx = float(argv[i+1])
            uly = float(argv[i+2])
            lrx = float(argv[i+3])
            lry = float(argv[i+4])
            i = i + 4

        elif arg[:1] == '-':
            print('Unrecognised command option: %s' % arg)
            Usage()
            sys.exit( 1 )

        else:
            filenames = glob(arg)
            names += filenames

        i = i + 1

    if len(names) == 0:
        print('No input files selected.')
        Usage()
        sys.exit( 1 )

    Driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
    if Driver is None:
        print('Format driver %s not found, pick a supported driver.' % format)
        sys.exit( 1 )

    DriverMD = Driver.GetMetadata()
    if 'DCAP_CREATE' not in DriverMD:
        print('Format driver %s does not support creation and piecewise writing.\nPlease select a format that does, such as GTiff (the default) or HFA (Erdas Imagine).' % format)
        sys.exit( 1 )

    # Collect information on all the source files.
    file_infos = names_to_fileinfos( names )

    if ulx is None:
        ulx = file_infos[0].ulx
        uly = file_infos[0].uly
        lrx = file_infos[0].lrx
        lry = file_infos[0].lry

        for fi in file_infos:
            ulx = min(ulx, fi.ulx)
            uly = max(uly, fi.uly)
            lrx = max(lrx, fi.lrx)
            lry = min(lry, fi.lry)

    if psize_x is None:
        psize_x = file_infos[0].geotransform[1]
        psize_y = file_infos[0].geotransform[5]

    if band_type is None:
        band_type = file_infos[0].band_type

    # Try opening as an existing file.
    gdal.PushErrorHandler( 'CPLQuietErrorHandler' )
    t_fh = gdal.Open( out_file, gdal.GA_Update )
    gdal.PopErrorHandler()

    # Create output file if it does not already exist.
    if t_fh is None:

        if bTargetAlignedPixels:
            ulx = math.floor(ulx / psize_x) * psize_x
            lrx = math.ceil(lrx / psize_x) * psize_x
            lry = math.floor(lry / -psize_y) * -psize_y
            uly = math.ceil(uly / -psize_y) * -psize_y

        geotransform = [ulx, psize_x, 0, uly, 0, psize_y]

        xsize = int((lrx - ulx) / geotransform[1] + 0.5)
        ysize = int((lry - uly) / geotransform[5] + 0.5)


        if separate != 0:
            bands=0

            for fi in file_infos:
                bands=bands + fi.bands
        else:
            bands = file_infos[0].bands


        t_fh = Driver.Create( out_file, xsize, ysize, bands,
                              band_type, create_options )
        if t_fh is None:
            print('Creation failed, terminating gdal_merge.')
            sys.exit( 1 )

        t_fh.SetGeoTransform( geotransform )
        t_fh.SetProjection( file_infos[0].projection )

        if copy_pct:
            t_fh.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorTable(file_infos[0].ct)
    else:
        if separate != 0:
            bands=0
            for fi in file_infos:
                bands=bands + fi.bands
            if t_fh.RasterCount < bands :
                print('Existing output file has less bands than the input files. You should delete it before. Terminating gdal_merge.')
                sys.exit( 1 )
        else:
            bands = min(file_infos[0].bands,t_fh.RasterCount)

    # Do we need to set nodata value ?
    if a_nodata is not None:
        for i in range(t_fh.RasterCount):
            t_fh.GetRasterBand(i+1).SetNoDataValue(a_nodata)

    # Do we need to pre-initialize the whole mosaic file to some value?
    if pre_init is not None:
        if t_fh.RasterCount <= len(pre_init):
            for i in range(t_fh.RasterCount):
                t_fh.GetRasterBand(i+1).Fill( pre_init[i] )
        elif len(pre_init) == 1:
            for i in range(t_fh.RasterCount):
                t_fh.GetRasterBand(i+1).Fill( pre_init[0] )

    # Copy data from source files into output file.
    t_band = 1

    if quiet == 0 and verbose == 0:
        progress( 0.0 )
    fi_processed = 0

    for fi in file_infos:
        if createonly != 0:
            continue

        if verbose != 0:
            print("")
            print("Processing file %5d of %5d, %6.3f%% completed." \
                  % (fi_processed+1,len(file_infos),
                     fi_processed * 100.0 / len(file_infos)) )
            fi.report()

        if separate == 0 :
            for band in range(1, bands+1):
                fi.copy_into( t_fh, band, band, nodata )
        else:
            for band in range(1, fi.bands+1):
                fi.copy_into( t_fh, band, t_band, nodata )
                t_band = t_band+1

        fi_processed = fi_processed+1
        if quiet == 0 and verbose == 0:
            progress( fi_processed / float(len(file_infos))  )

    # Force file to be closed.
    t_fh = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Use:

```py
merge_command = ["python3","gdal_merge.py", "-n","-2","-a_nodata","-2","-o", "doubleminustwoResult.tif", "result2.envi", "result1.envi"]
result = subprocess.run(merge_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stderr)
print(result.returncode)
print(result.stdout)
```